# Crazy slow ssd speeds with a Samsung 850 evo

Tags: release-freya, ssd

I just ran

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=./largefile bs=1M count=1024
```

and got "1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 10.2641 s, 105 MB/s"

read speeds are only 20 MB/s faster.

I ran the dsmeg grep thing and my laptop def. is sata 6gb/s And my bios has AHCI on.
So I don't know what it could be. Anyone else have this drive? Can you test your speeds? This thing is supposed to be rated for 500 MB/s read and write!

(edited to main question)

Comment: Please check alignments of your partition(s). In terminal type ´sudo parted /dev/sda align-check opt` for every partition. If everything is OK, you will get <PARTITION-NO> aligned

Comment: Well, number 2 is not aligned. The others are. But Disks (gnome-disks-utility) says it's just an extended partition. I'm not sure what this means or if this is the source of my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same drive (250gb, 1 month old). I ran same command as you and got

```
1073741824 bytes (1,1 GB) copied, 1,29003 s, 832 MB/s
```

which didn't seem right :D With second try I got

```
1073741824 bytes (1,1 GB) copied, 2,28104 s, 471 MB/s
```

and with third try 543 MB/s.

With reading, I got

```
1073741824 bytes (1,1 GB) copied, 2,0356 s, 527 MB/s
```

They seem to be in line with specifications. I am sorry I can't help more with your problem.

EDIT: Is this reliable benchmark? I tried one more time and got 1400 MB/s when writing new file. When overwriting I get those ~500

Comment: How strange. I tried another benchmark and got 500 reads. But for this one I keep getting 120 or so. I will try one a proper one and if that seems off I guess I will format and reinstall or something.

Comment: maybe this tutorial could help https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization